# What is a good Manual/Guide class in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I am writing a manual/guide for our intranet using LaTeX.

I am wondering if there are classes developed for this purpose? A search returns results that are manuals about using LaTeX.

Spefically I want to make use of "hint" boxes and the like (Floating boxes in a guide that have a short hint or some such thing). I find the way these stand out from the rest of the text really draws in the readers attention.

Perhaps there is a better -- read less complex -- way of going about this using the standard book or article class?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, better [ask your question over her ...](http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Should I mark this as the accepted answer or post a link to the thread on tex.stackexchange?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to do both ...

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this question I have come across the bclogo package. Documentation [here](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/bclogo/doc/bclogo-doc.pdf) in French.

The package seems to be able to create very beautiful boxes whilst allowing the user to use the standard books class.